# Тесты для собеседования на junior Ruby developer

Tags: ruby, тестирование

Планирую в ближайшее время устроиться на ruby разработчика, знаю, что частно на собеседованиях спрашивают тесты.

Может, кто-нибудь знает, где можно взять такие тесты?

Comment: Вы уверены, что "частно на собеседованиях спрашивают тесты" - это не про тестирование?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На http://muliver.org можно пройти тесты по ruby, хотя здесь их и не много.

Answer (score 0):

Codewars, ruby koans, project euler. Хотя что за тесты спрашивают, может, minitest?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сети задачки *[Ruby Code Kata](http://www.sitepoint.com/code-kata/)* и [Сoders dojo](http://content.codersdojo.org/home/)